# How would I go about computing this finite sum?

Tags: summation

How would I go about computing the sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{(-k^2+2k+1)2^k}{(k(k+1))^2}.
$$

I have tried partial fractions but have gotten stuck trying to find the coefficients. I decomposed it like this:
$$
\dfrac{2^k(-k^2+2k+1)}{(k(k+1))^2} = \frac{a_0}{k} + \frac{a_1}{k^2} + \frac{a_2}{k+1} + \frac{a_3}{(k+1)^2}
$$.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried partial fractions or simply rewriting the numerator?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: What make you think there is a "closed formula". It is very likely that no such formula exists. As suggested by Simply Beautiful Art, you could at least try by re-writing the numerator under the form $-(k^2+k)+(3k+1)$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt see edit.

Comment: You don't want the $2^k$ in your partial fractions. First do the partial fractions of $\frac{-k^2+2k+1}{[k(k+1)]^2}$, then multiply the whole thing by $2^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Without the need for solving the coefficients:

$\dfrac{-k^2+2k+1}{k^2(k+1)^2} =\dfrac{k^2+2k+1-2k^2}{k^2(k+1)^2}=\dfrac{(k+1)^2}{k^2(k+1)^2}-\dfrac{2}{(k+1)^2}=\dfrac{1}{k^2}-\dfrac{2}{(k+1)^2}.$

Thus, the sum is reduced to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^k}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{k+1}}{(k+1)^2}.$$

And then note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{k+1}}{(k+1)^2}=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k^2}=-2+\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k^2}.$$

The rest is for you to finish.

Comment: The denominator is $[k(k+1)]^2$, not $k(k+1)^2$.

Comment: Thanks for noting, that will change alot..

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$\dfrac{(-k^2+2k+1)2^k}{(k(k+1))^2}= \dfrac{-2^{k+1}}{(k+1)^2}+\dfrac{2^k}{k^2}.$$

Then take sum as $k$ varies from $1$ to $n$.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{-2^{k+1}}{(k+1)^2}+\dfrac{2^k}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{-2^{k+1}}{(k+1)^2}+\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{2^k}{k^2}$$

This being an alternate sum of elements of same type, you are left with $$2-\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}$$

Comment: In my honest opinion, this should be a comment. There's no explanation, and there's no answer in this "answer".

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt This is a hint...

Comment: Being a hint is not excuse for a poor answer.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I can’t convince you.. upto you to think what ever you want to think

Answer (score 0):

The partial fraction expansion gives
$$
{{ - k^{\,2}  + 2k + 1} \over {\left( {k\left( {k + 1} \right)} \right)^2 }} = {1 \over {k^{\,2} }} - {2 \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2} }}
$$

Then we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{u^{\,k} } \over k} = \int_{t = 0}^{\,u} {t^{\,k - 1} dt} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad {{x^{\,k} } \over {k^{\,2} }} = \int_{u = 0}^x {{{du} \over u}\int_{t = 0}^{\,u} {t^{\,k - 1} dt} } \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad {{x^{\,k} } \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2} }} = {1 \over x}\int_{u = 0}^x {{{du} \over u}\int_{t = 0}^{\,u} {t^{\,k} dt} }  \cr} 
$$
so that 
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{{ - k^{\,2}  + 2k + 1} \over {\left( {k\left( {k + 1} \right)} \right)^2 }}x^{\,k} }
  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{{x^{\,k} } \over {k^{\,2} }}}  - 2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{{x^{\,k} } \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2} }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{u = 0}^x {{{du} \over u}\int_{t = 0}^{\,u} {t^{\,k - 1} dt} } }  - 2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{1 \over x}\int_{u = 0}^x {{{du} \over u}\int_{t = 0}^{\,u} {t^{\,k} dt} } }  \cr} 
$$

In particular for $x=2$ we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{{ - k^{\,2}  + 2k + 1} \over {\left( {k\left( {k + 1} \right)} \right)^2 }}2^{\,k} }
  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{u = 0}^2 {{{du} \over u}\int_{t = 0}^{\,u} {t^{\,k - 1} dt} } }  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{u = 0}^2 {{{du} \over u}\int_{t = 0}^{\,u} {t^{\,k} dt} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{u = 0}^2 {{{du} \over u}\int_{t = 0}^{\,u} {t^{\,k - 1} dt} } }  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{u = 0}^2 {{{du} \over u}\int_{t = 0}^{\,u} {t^{\,k} dt} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{u = 0}^2 {{{du} \over u}\int_{t = 0}^{\,u} {t^{\,k - 1} \left( {1 - t} \right)dt} } }  =   \cr 
  &  =  \cdots  \cr} 
$$

Can you continue from here ?

(the solution is
$
2 - {{2^{n + 1} } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,2} }}
$
)